# If I format a partition in ubuntu 16.04 as Ext4 using Gparted...will it be hidden in Windows 10?

Tags: partitioning, windows, gparted, ext4

First of all I'm new to Ubuntu...In **windows 10**, I have my own 195 GB **(NTFS)** partition where I keep all my personal files & folders...now I want this partition to be accessible only from **Ubuntu 16.04.01 LTS**...will **formatting** this partition in **Ext4** from ubuntu will help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Windows cannot read ext4 at all, it won't even recognize it as connected.

Bare in mind, formatting the drive will wipe all the data on the drive.